# Bootstrap - fill a row with fixed size divs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Please see my code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/0tkWm0KULWuThaC176Iu?p=preview)

I have a div.row and a number of red divs inside this row, these red divs are all fixed size.
I want to align all red divs so that:

1. it fills as many red divs as possible in a row
2. either all the divs are centered in the row, or div margin is calculated properly so they fill up whole row width. Currently there can be unused space on the right hand side.

how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a bootstrap row can contain up to 12 columns, or columns of various widths or offsets adding up to 12. So, you can only have 6 `col-xs-2` in one row, or 12 `col-xs-1`, or 3 `col-xs-4`, etc. There are many ways to customize and expand on this, such as nested columns. Just take a look at the [Bootstrap grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

If you want content centered on the page, surround it with a div with class `container`.

If you want the divs to automatically adjust their widths, you need to remove the `width: 100px;` from your css.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ringstaff/N82QD/2/).